# TypeError: this.state.schedulelistnew.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Create class 'ScheduleList' and initalize array elements

```
class ScheduleList extends Component {
      state = {
        schedulelistnew: []
    };
```

Used to populate array elements from API using axios

```
 componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://apiv2.apifootball.com/?action=get_H2H&firstTeam=Chelsea&secondTeam=Arsenal&APIkey=******`)
        .then(res => {
           const schedulelistnew = res.data;
          this.setState({ schedulelistnew });
        });
      }
```

Render the array elements to the Component 'ScheduleListItem '

```
 render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Row>
              <Col lg="9" md="8">
                {this.state.schedulelistnew.map(item => (
                  <div className="strong textmb-3 pb-2" key={item.match_id}>
                    <ScheduleListItem item={item} />
                  </div>
                ))}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: can you share the reponse from the API

Comment: @Christin Chacko, could you check res.data? I think `res.data` is not an array.

Comment: {"firstTeam_VS_secondTeam":[{"match_id":"224432","country_id":"41","country_name":"England","league_id":"148","league_name":"Premier League","match_date":"2019-08-11","match_status":"Finished","match_time":"15:00","match_hometeam_id":"2630","match_hometeam_name":"Newcastle","match_hometeam_score":"0","match_awayteam_id":"2617","match_awayteam_name":"Arsenal","match_awayteam_score":"1","match_hometeam_halftime_score":"0","match_awayteam_halftime_score":"0","match_live":"0"}]}

Comment: res.data returns multiple array of data.Then the code changed to const schedulelistnew = res.data.firstTeam_VS_secondTeam; than const schedulelistnew = res.data;

Answer (score -1):

when the map process you forget about return

```
{this.state.schedulelistnew.map( item => {
    return (
      <div className="strong textmb-3 pb-2" key={item.match_id}>
        <ScheduleListItem item={item} />
      </div>
   );
  }
)}
```

Comment: using the arrow syntax you dont need a return statement

Comment: Have you tried it?

because I also experienced the same case after I added the return it worked ..